# Angular module on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have a existing controller and template:

```
<div id="outputTableforApp" ng-controller="OutputTableModelCtrl">
    <div id ="outputtablemodel_panel" ng-show="editMode">
    </div>
</div>
```

it works perfectly. But now i need to delete the template from the project (which has a fix place in the DOM) and somehow make it appear dynamically when man a button click.
when i tried that with jQuery

```
$('<div id="outputTableforApp" ng-controller="OutputTableModelCtrl"><div id ="outputtablemodel_panel" ng-show="editMode">\n\
</div></div>').appendTo($('#div1'));
```

My Angular module didn't work at all. So i guess i need to register the module somehow again every time when someone presses the button, is that the case ? if so ,how could i do it ?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery and angular like that. Recommended reading: [Thinking in Angular if I have a jQuery background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-show` so do this:

```
<div id="outputTableforApp" ng-controller="OutputTableModelCtrl" ng-show="showApp">
```

and when the button is clicked call a function (using `ng-click`) in your `controller` script that makes it that `showApp` is `true`(make sure you use `$scope.showApp` in the function).

Comment: you mean like that  after adding ng-show="showApp"?
 angular.element($('#outputTableforApp')).scope().showApp=true;

Comment: I was thinking `angular.module('AppName', []).controller('OutputTableModelCtrl' , function($scope){$scope.showDiv=function(){$scope.showApp=true}; });` and in the button add `ng-click="showDiv()"`

Comment: Also make sure you have `showApp` set to false when it's loaded so it isn't showing when he page loads. You can do that by putting `ng-init="showApp=false"` in the top `div` or you can put `$scope.showApp=false;` before the `$scope.showDiv=function`  in my previous comment